# javascript for creating link url from elements w/o specific IDs

Tags: javascript

In a CMS that returns a list of results from a search, I have a list of items that looks something like this:

```
<ul class="results_odd_row">
  <li class=title> Title </li>
  <li class=published> Year </li>
  <li class="author"> Author </li>
  <li class="avail"> Out; try <a href="http://another.search">Another Search</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="results_even_row">... </ul>
<ul class="results_odd_row">... </ul>
...etc...
```

For the "try another search" link, I'd like to append onto the url some information about the record, like "http://another.search?title=[title]&author=[author]", so that information can be used to execute the other search.

How can I identify elements that have no specific ID, and where there are multiple elements of the same class on the same page? In pseudo code, what I want might be something like:

```
 1. href = base URL (http://another.search) plus
 2. the text from the first <li> element above with class="title"
 3. the text from the first <li> element above with class="author"
```

Also, I'm limited by the CMS to whatever javascript I can use within the A tag.

If it's not already obvious, I'm a complete newbie with javascript, so please don't feel your potential response is insultingly basic.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your query string in this way

```
var baseUrl = "http://another.search"
var author = $('.results_even_row .author, .results_odd_row .author').first().text();
var title = $('.results_even_row .title, .results_odd_row .title').first().text();

var queryString = baseUrl + "?title=[" + title + "]&author=[" + author + "]"
```

Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/markus85/y5gsH/).

Then you just use this string for the next search.